# Expectation Value of the BCS Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, condensed-matter, conductors, superconductivity

I want to calculate the expectation value of the BCS Hamiltonian
$ H = \sum_k E(k) c_k^\dagger c_k - \frac{V}{2} \sum_{k,q} c_{k+q}^\dagger c_{-k-q}^\dagger c_{-k} c_k $
in the state $| \Psi \rangle = \prod_k a(k) c_k^\dagger c_{-k}^\dagger | G \rangle $.
I know it can be expressed as

$ \langle H \rangle_{\Psi} = 2 \sum_k E(k) |a(k)|^2 - V \sum_{k,q} a^*(k + q) a(k)$

but I come to the similar and slightly confusing result

$ \langle H \rangle_{\Psi}^{wrong?} = 2 \sum_k E(k) (|a(k)|^2 - a^*(k)a(-k)) - V \sum_{k,q} (a^*(k + q) a(k)- a^*(k + q) a(-k))$.

This result could still be valid if the sums over $a^*(k) a(-k))$ etc. vanish, but i see no reason for that to be the case.
As I understood the $c^\dagger$ operators are just regular fermion (electron creation) operators with  $\{c^\dagger_p, c_q\} = \delta_{pq}$ and they annihilate the BCS ground state as in $c_q|G\rangle = 0$.

Do I need to consider properties of the functions $E(k)$ or $a(k)$? I guess $a(k)$ should be square integrable or something and the single particle energy $E(k)$ should be spherically symmetric, giving us $E(k) = E(-k)$.

Thanks!